# Play Youtube video from Flex app

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, youtube

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on what the best way to embed a youtube player inside a flex app is. I've looked around and it seems that one can

- Try to use SWFLoader (as with what's described [here](http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2010/11/youtube-videos-in-flex.html)) but this ends up throwing crossdomain violations
- Use the YouTuve API
- Ideally use the Spark VideoPlayer component, although I have not been able to figure out how to play a YouTube video through it and am starting to think that it is, in fact, not possible.

Would love to hear any thoughts from those of you out there that have done this in the past.

thank you!

Comment: Have you seen this? http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2010/11/youtube-videos-in-flex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trying a variety of things, I've come to the conclusion that the Youtube API is probably the best way to go, but it doesn't work very well, at least it seems to have all sorts of issues in Flex 4 (see for instance http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/f8e61440e5f1a21c/9ed01ed5fd6eb71b). The interesting thing is that the serious security errors seem to happen only if you move the mouse pointer over the Application stage. So if you can stomach to cover your whole application with something (at least a rect wrapped in a group) you should be ok. Ugly as hell, but that seems to be the only way I can find to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the most convenient way is using youtube api. Check [this turotial](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html).

Comment: Yeah! Just use the Youtube API for flash/flex!

Comment: hey there, thank you for pointing this out! I tried all the examples I could find and still get all sorts of security violations. There doesn't seem to be a decent working examples anywhere on the web - extremely frustrating. Do you know of any links out there that actually work?

Comment: More specifically, this seems to hold true for me (http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/04f42121ae0b7d83)

Answer (score 1):

SWF-Loader cross-domain exceptions, add the following line to your code, BEFORE the player gets initialized.

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
```